# Why is the continuity equation only valid for the flux velocity but not for the osmotic velocity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conservation-laws, diffusion, stochastic-processes, randomness

The continuity equation

$$  \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec v \rho) = 0  , $$

can be derived from the Fokker-Planck equations for the forward- and backward velocity ($b,b^\star)$:

$$  \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec b \rho) = D \nabla^2 \rho ,  $$ 
$$  \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec b^* \rho) =- D \nabla^2 \rho .  $$ 
To show this, we need the formula $\vec v \equiv \frac{1}{2} (b+b^\star)$.

However, if we subtract the two Fokker-Planck equation in order to find an equation for the osmotic velocity $\vec u \equiv \frac{1}{2} (b-b^\star)$, we don't find a continuity equation:
$$ \nabla (\vec u \rho) = D \nabla^2 \, . $$
Both, $\vec v $ and $\vec u$ describe the motions of the particles in question. Hence, I would have expected that the diffusive motion described by $\vec u$ also follows a continuity equation. After all, if all the particles do a random walk, there is no teleportation and no production of particles.

What's the physical reason that the equation
$$  \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec u \rho) = 0  , $$ 
is wrong?